# My animation disapears because of opacity

Tags: css, animation

Why is my animation disapearing, I've tried to set `opacity:1!important`, I've tried to change to `visibility hidden and visible` it still gives the same result. My div should be hidden for two sec, (`animation-delay`) then my animation runs perfectly. Then it disappers everytime.... even tho it's at opacity 1, I dont get it, am I some kind of idiot? https://jsfiddle.net/padvyzk5/

```css
.welcome{  
  animation: drop 1.5s ease;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  transition: 1s;
  opacity:0;
  font-size: min(2.5vw, 32px);
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -6%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  background-color: #254C5B;
}
@keyframes drop{
  from {
    opacity:0; 
    transform: translateY(-80px);
  }
  to {
      opacity:1; 
      transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<h3 class ='welcome'> Welcome</h3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` now your animation is running and just going back to its initial state.

```
.welcome{  
  animation: drop 1.5s ease;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition: 1s;
  opacity:0;
  font-size: min(2.5vw, 32px);
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -6%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  background-color: #254C5B;
}
@keyframes drop{
  from {
    opacity:0; 
    transform: translateY(-80px);
  }
  to {
      opacity:1; 
      transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```